# InvalidateBlock RPC call behavior with Bitcoin Core

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, json-rpc, bitcoin-cli, chain-reorganization

I'm currently implementing the rpc call `invalidateblock` on btcd, an alternate Bitcoin full node implementation. I'm trying to figure out how Bitcoin Core handles branch selection on reorganizations with `invalidateblock`.

Say there's 3 chaintips like so:

```
genesis -> 1  -> 2  -> 3  (active)     (chainwork=8)
       \-> 1a             (valid-fork) (chainwork=4)
       \-> 1b             (valid-fork) (chainwork=6)
```

Blocks at height 1 were received in the order of: `1, 1a, 1b`. Block `1` was received most recently and block `1b` was received last.

If I call `invalidateblock` on block 2, which block will become the active chaintip?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The same rules apply as during normal active-chain selection:

1. Ignore all known-invalid blocks and their descendants
2. Of what remains, keep only the tips with the most chainwork
3. If there are multiple of those max-chainwork valid tips, pick the one which was received first.

So in your example it would depend on how much chainwork `genesis+1` has. If it's more than 6, `1` would win. If it's less than 6, `1b` would win. If it is equal to 6, it will depend on whether `1` or `1b` was received first.

Comment: Follow up question:

Suppose I called `invalidateblock` on block `3`. `genesis+1+2`'s chainwork is 6. If block `1b`'s chainwork is 7, would the active chain tip now be `1b`?

Comment: @kcalvinalvin Yes, the history is not relevant in determining what the new best block becomes, given the set of blocks, their validity, their chainwork, and their time of receiving, you can always determine what the active chaintip becomes.